# How to perform multiple functions (distinct-values, count) on a variable in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, distinct-values

I have an XML file with the following entries:

```
<file>
 <unit id="u-1.01"/>
 <unit id="u-1.02"/>
 <unit id="u-1.03"/>
 <unit id="u-1.04"/>
 <unit id="u-1.05"/>
 <unit id="u-1.06"/>
 <unit id="u-1.07"/>
 <unit id="u-2.01"/>
 <unit id="u-2.02"/>
 <unit id="u-2.03"/>
 <unit id="u-2.04"/>
 <unit id="u-2.05"/>
 <unit id="u-2.06"/>
</file>
```

I want to count the number of distinct-values using the query below.

The query goes through each of the *@id* attributes and selects the third character in the string.

```
declare function local:count-base-pages($basefile) {
for $identifiers in $basefile/unit/@id
let $id := distinct-values(substring($identifiers, 3, 1)) 
return count($id) 
};
```

However, this query returns the following sequence:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

The wished outcome would be `2` because there are two distinct values: 1 and 2.

How am I misusing the *distinct-values* and *count* functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your functions around the actual FLWOR expression: `count(distinct-values(for ... return ...))`

Answer (score 1):

**Use the shorter**:

```
count(distinct-values(/*/*/@id/substring(.,3,1)))
```

**Performing the above XQuery on the provided XML document**:

```
<file>
 <unit id="u-1.01"/>
 <unit id="u-1.02"/>
 <unit id="u-1.03"/>
 <unit id="u-1.04"/>
 <unit id="u-1.05"/>
 <unit id="u-1.06"/>
 <unit id="u-1.07"/>
 <unit id="u-2.01"/>
 <unit id="u-2.02"/>
 <unit id="u-2.03"/>
 <unit id="u-2.04"/>
 <unit id="u-2.05"/>
 <unit id="u-2.06"/>
</file>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
2
```